# Query not timing out when using Spring Core JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-midrange, jdbctemplate

I am working on a spring boot app, one of the methods that queries a ibm db2 db won't timeout per the set values. The datasource is managed by **tomcat**. is this the correct way of handling the query timeouts? I am expecting a sql timeout exception, when the query timeouts, but it's not happening for me.

Database Driver: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver

```
try {

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    int timeout = dataSourceConfig.getTimeout();
    jdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout(timeout);
    Result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[]{Params....}, String.class);

} catch(DataAccessException ex){
    log.error("Error Occurred :" + ex.getMessage());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Error Occurred :" + ex.getMessage());
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is if I am doing this correctly, this query needs to timeout after 30 seconds if not results returned, but that is not happening. I am expecting a sql timeout exception, but it's current not happening.